# Warn user method will not work without params argument

Tags: c#, methods

I am developing a C# NuGet library that has a method which has a params parameter. The method operates with that parameter's argument and calling it with no argument does nothing. But, since it's "params" the user can, legally, call the method with no argument for that parameter.

Is it possible to somehow generate a warning or an error for the user if he does not provide said argument?

This isn't a code analyzer solution, as I won't be able to influence the environment of the user and I know I can throw an exception, but would prefer to warn the user beforehand.

Comment: make the first param a free standing argument and the rest be `params` then they have to give at least one arg

Comment: @pm100, yes but that would prevent the user from using a collection in one go. Which is to say if they have a collection/array that they want to give the method they won't be able to without also, annoyingly, giving a random argument or fiddling with it.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: so have 2 overloads one with 'IEnumerable' and one with 'arg1,params'

Comment: @JuanR, .Net 6.

Comment: @pm100, back to square one with the overload with doesn't have the free standing argument.

Comment: If you are using `params`, even if the user passes nothing, you still end up with an empty array, so basically you need to decide if your current implementation matches your requirements. If calling it with no parameters is allowed, then why warn the user? If it is not allowed, using `params` is not the right way to implement this. You are trying to warn the user at compile time for a condition that you created by trying to add syntactic sugar.

Comment: @JuanR, I chose `params` to facilitate the user by making it so that he can enter any number of arguments, without worrying whether it's a List, IEnum, Array, etc. You are right about me creating the problem for some syntactic sugar. In your opinion, it is wrong what I am doing, yes?

Comment: Yes. In my opinion, your method should receive a valid parameter and as such, either you enforce that through the contract (signature) or check the value internally and throw an exception. I personally would use `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type you expect and call it a day. Let the consumer figure out what is passed to you. I would still check for `null` or an empty enumerable inside the method.

Comment: @JuanR, I believe you are right. I realize now the tiny pleasure of being able to add arguments, without declaring a collection, does not outweigh the problems it causes if called with no arguments. For clarity, could you elaborate what you meant by "either you enforce that through the contract (signature) **or check the value internally and throw an exception**"

Comment: Sure. Basically, the definition of your signature can enforce this to some extent. For instance `(int? x)` vs. `(int x)`. It gets a little more tricky with reference types. Later versions of the compiler include attributes that can help control this (e.g. `[DisallowNull]`) but it requires that you enable nullable context in the project. Another option is to validate your parameters as you enter the method (which you should be doing anyways) and throw `ArgumentException` exceptions as needed. You can also use classes in the  `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` namespace.

Comment: @JuanR, I understand what you mean, but `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` is deprecated / best practice is not to use it anymore, right? Also, as I understand it, making the method take `params` and throw an exception if the user uses it with no `params` is worse than just using IEnum, right?

Comment: I don't know that it's "worse" per se. the `params` keyword itself is syntactical sugar. The compiler will internally just create an array and pass it for you. I prefer interfaces because they hide the actual objects and do not rely on compiler features (more portable). From the point of view of your method, you expect to work with an enumeration of items which would be clear to the consumer who doesn't know anything about your internals if you use an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Last thought. The fact that you are spending time trying to figure out how to contain this should be a red flag in itself. When this happens, it usually signals you should take a step back and rethink your design (which is what I did for you :-).

Comment: @JuanR, yup, you're right. We live and we learn. :)